# Using two parameters to loop in python, output of one loop as input of next loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a really basic calculation that I want to loop:

```
month = 1
carryK = 104800 #Carrying capacity as per Q0
redcarryK = 0.998 #amount to reduce the carrying capacity to as given in part 4
newcarryK = (carryK*redcarryK)
```

I want to loop this calculation through a 12 month cycle so that the newcarryK for month 1 then becomes carryK for month2.

I've tried if's and while's and all I get is an output of the same answer 12 times.

```
while month <=12:
    print newcarryK
    month = month + 1
```

Comment: add `newcarryK = (newcarryK*redcarryK)` below `print newcarryK` line or simply use `carryK` instead of `newcarryK`. You need to update the value inside the loop.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - it's always the really simple things that stump me! :-(

Comment: If this is homework, make sure to add the homework tag!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like newcarryk calculation is missing.

```
while month <=12:
    print newcarryK
    newcarryK = (newcarryK*redcarryK)
    month = month + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, this calculation is the classical compound interest calculation. Let us redefine `carryK = p` and `redcarryK == r` for brevity.

Now, for each month, the calculation proceeds as:

```
month 1 --> p * r
month 2 --> p * r ** 2
month 3 --> p * r ** 3
month 4 --> p * r ** 4
```

I guess you see the pattern. The program you are using is a very traditinal procedural method. A more Pythonic way would be the following:

```
p = 104800
r = 0.998
vals = [ p * r ** i for i in range(1, 13)]
```

When learning Python, try to use list comprehensions etc which significantly improves readability ...